# Why ring oscillator showing irregular graph ?

Tags: clock, cmos, vlsi

I'm trying to design ring oscillator in CADENCE using 180 CMOS .Instead of showing inverted clocking output , output changes in less then millivolt ranges. When I connect only 9 inverter like this schematic:
[image]

output graph for last 3 nodes are like this:
[image]

zoomed view of this graph is:
[image]

this changes happening in less then nanovolt rage which should be considered as nothing but noise ( I presume )

If I increase the number of CMOS significantly (45 CMOS) then this graph become this where variation still do not cross milivolt range:
[image]

I did not do any calculation for this, as for a simulation purpose, I thought it would not be necessary I'm not looking for any specific frequency right now.Provided mosfet should be sufficient for sample design.

Where could I make mistakes ? What kind of calculation should I do to fast to design this ring oscillator properly ?

Comment: Try setting an initial condition on one gate, it may be hunting for a stable solution, which is of course not there. Do the CMOS models include capacitance?

Comment: Yes, CMOS include capacitance. There is no initial condition set up option at gate. But if I use a capacitor and its initial voltage 0 then it works fine. But in practical case , I can't use a capacitor there and there will be no chance to set up initial condition. will it be a problem ?

Comment: Looks like it might simply be aliasing between the actual waveform and the points where it is sampled. I'd eliminate that possibility before worrying about what the circuit is actually doing.

Comment: @Anklon You can use a very very very small capacitor as a hook to hang an initial condition on, 1fF or 1aF for instance, you would expect larger differences between ring oscillator stages in real manufacturing.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have access to CADENCE.

But the first thing that hits me in the head right away is that your PMOS widths need to be twice (or more?) the width of your NMOS due to mobility. You probably want 20:1 on the PMOS and 10:1 on the NMOS, or something about like that. So when using \$\textrm{w}=2\:\mu\$ for your NMOS then use \$\textrm{w}=4\:\mu\$ for your PMOS.

Other than that, I don't yet see other problems. But I don't have your models and levels, either. (I use LTspice, only.)

---

Here is an example of my run using 9 stages:

[image]

Here's the schematic in LTspice I used:

[image]

---

Another possibility is the underlying models you are using. The detailed models I'm using are here:

```
.model  N_50n  nmos  level = 54
+binunit = 1            paramchk= 1            mobmod  = 0          
+capmod  = 2            igcmod  = 1            igbmod  = 1            geomod  = 0          
+diomod  = 1            rdsmod  = 0            rbodymod= 1            rgatemod= 1          
+permod  = 1            acnqsmod= 0            trnqsmod= 0          
+tnom    = 27           toxe    = 1.4e-009     toxp    = 7e-010       toxm    = 1.4e-009   
+epsrox  = 3.9          wint    = 5e-009       lint    = 1.2e-008   
+ll      = 0            wl      = 0            lln     = 1            wln     = 1          
+lw      = 0            ww      = 0            lwn     = 1            wwn     = 1          
+lwl     = 0            wwl     = 0            xpart   = 0            toxref  = 1.4e-009   
+vth0    = 0.22         k1      = 0.35         k2      = 0.05         k3      = 0          
+k3b     = 0            w0      = 2.5e-006     dvt0    = 2.8          dvt1    = 0.52       
+dvt2    = -0.032       dvt0w   = 0            dvt1w   = 0            dvt2w   = 0          
+dsub    = 2            minv    = 0.05         voffl   = 0            dvtp0   = 1e-007     
+dvtp1   = 0.05         lpe0    = 5.75e-008    lpeb    = 2.3e-010     xj      = 2e-008     
+ngate   = 5e+020       ndep    = 2.8e+018     nsd     = 1e+020       phin    = 0          
+cdsc    = 0.0002       cdscb   = 0            cdscd   = 0            cit     = 0          
+voff    = -0.15        nfactor = 1.2          eta0    = 0.15         etab    = 0          
+vfb     = -0.55        u0      = 0.032        ua      = 1.6e-010     ub      = 1.1e-017   
+uc      = -3e-011      vsat    = 1.1e+005     a0      = 2            ags     = 1e-020     
+a1      = 0            a2      = 1            b0      = -1e-020      b1      = 0          
+keta    = 0.04         dwg     = 0            dwb     = 0            pclm    = 0.18       
+pdiblc1 = 0.028        pdiblc2 = 0.022        pdiblcb = -0.005       drout   = 0.45       
+pvag    = 1e-020       delta   = 0.01         pscbe1  = 8.14e+008    pscbe2  = 1e-007     
+fprout  = 0.2          pdits   = 0.2          pditsd  = 0.23         pditsl  = 2.3e+006   
+rsh     = 3            rdsw    = 150          rsw     = 150          rdw     = 150        
+rdswmin = 0            rdwmin  = 0            rswmin  = 0            prwg    = 0          
+prwb    = 6.8e-011     wr      = 1            alpha0  = 0.074        alpha1  = 0.005      
+beta0   = 30           agidl   = 0.0002       bgidl   = 2.1e+009     cgidl   = 0.0002     
+egidl   = 0.8          
+aigbacc = 0.012        bigbacc = 0.0028       cigbacc = 0.002
+nigbacc = 1            aigbinv = 0.014        bigbinv = 0.004        cigbinv = 0.004
+eigbinv = 1.1          nigbinv = 3            aigc    = 0.017        bigc    = 0.0028
+cigc    = 0.002        aigsd   = 0.017        bigsd   = 0.0028       cigsd   = 0.002
+nigc    = 1            poxedge = 1            pigcd   = 1            ntox    = 1
+xrcrg1  = 12           xrcrg2  = 5          
+cgso    = 6.238e-010   cgdo    = 6.238e-010   cgbo    = 2.56e-011    cgdl    = 2.495e-10     
+cgsl    = 2.495e-10    ckappas = 0.02         ckappad = 0.02         acde    = 1          
+moin    = 15           noff    = 0.9          voffcv  = 0.02       
+kt1     = -0.21        kt1l    = 0.0           kt2     = -0.042        ute     = -1.5
+ua1     = 1e-009       ub1     = -3.5e-019     uc1     = 0             prt     = 0
+at      = 53000
+fnoimod = 1            tnoimod = 0          
+jss     = 0.0001       jsws    = 1e-011       jswgs   = 1e-010       njs     = 1          
+ijthsfwd= 0.01         ijthsrev= 0.001        bvs     = 10           xjbvs   = 1          
+jsd     = 0.0001       jswd    = 1e-011       jswgd   = 1e-010       njd     = 1          
+ijthdfwd= 0.01         ijthdrev= 0.001        bvd     = 10           xjbvd   = 1          
+pbs     = 1            cjs     = 0.0005       mjs     = 0.5          pbsws   = 1          
+cjsws   = 5e-010       mjsws   = 0.33         pbswgs  = 1            cjswgs  = 5e-010     
+mjswgs  = 0.33         pbd     = 1            cjd     = 0.0005       mjd     = 0.5        
+pbswd   = 1            cjswd   = 5e-010       mjswd   = 0.33         pbswgd  = 1          
+cjswgd  = 5e-010       mjswgd  = 0.33         tpb     = 0.005        tcj     = 0.001      
+tpbsw   = 0.005        tcjsw   = 0.001        tpbswg  = 0.005        tcjswg  = 0.001      
+xtis    = 3            xtid    = 3          
+dmcg    = 0e-006       dmci    = 0e-006       dmdg    = 0e-006       dmcgt   = 0e-007     
+dwj     = 0e-008       xgw     = 0e-007       xgl     = 0e-008     
+rshg    = 0.4          gbmin   = 1e-010       rbpb    = 5            rbpd    = 15         
+rbps    = 15           rbdb    = 15           rbsb    = 15           ngcon   = 1
*
.model  P_50n  pmos  level = 54
+binunit = 1            paramchk= 1            mobmod  = 0          
+capmod  = 2            igcmod  = 1            igbmod  = 1            geomod  = 0          
+diomod  = 1            rdsmod  = 0            rbodymod= 1            rgatemod= 1          
+permod  = 1            acnqsmod= 0            trnqsmod= 0          
+tnom    = 27           toxe    = 1.4e-009     toxp    = 7e-010       toxm    = 1.4e-009   
+epsrox  = 3.9          wint    = 5e-009       lint    = 1.2e-008   
+ll      = 0            wl      = 0            lln     = 1            wln     = 1          
+lw      = 0            ww      = 0            lwn     = 1            wwn     = 1          
+lwl     = 0            wwl     = 0            xpart   = 0            toxref  = 1.4e-009   
+vth0    = -0.22        k1      = 0.39         k2      = 0.05         k3      = 0          
+k3b     = 0            w0      = 2.5e-006     dvt0    = 3.9          dvt1    = 0.635        
+dvt2    = -0.032       dvt0w   = 0            dvt1w   = 0            dvt2w   = 0          
+dsub    = 0.7          minv    = 0.05         voffl   = 0            dvtp0   = 0.5e-008     
+dvtp1   = 0.05         lpe0    = 5.75e-008    lpeb    = 2.3e-010     xj      = 2e-008     
+ngate   = 5e+020       ndep    = 2.8e+018     nsd     = 1e+020       phin    = 0          
+cdsc    = 0.000258     cdscb   = 0            cdscd   = 6.1e-008     cit     = 0          
+voff    = -0.15        nfactor = 2            eta0    = 0.15         etab    = 0          
+vfb     = 0.55         u0      = 0.0095       ua      = 1.6e-009     ub      = 8e-018     
+uc      = 4.6e-013     vsat    = 90000        a0      = 1.2          ags     = 1e-020     
+a1      = 0            a2      = 1            b0      = -1e-020      b1      = 0          
+keta    = -0.047       dwg     = 0            dwb     = 0            pclm    = 0.55       
+pdiblc1 = 0.03         pdiblc2 = 0.0055       pdiblcb = 3.4e-008     drout   = 0.56       
+pvag    = 1e-020       delta   = 0.014        pscbe1  = 8.14e+008    pscbe2  = 9.58e-007  
+fprout  = 0.2          pdits   = 0.2          pditsd  = 0.23         pditsl  = 2.3e+006   
+rsh     = 3            rdsw    = 250          rsw     = 160          rdw     = 160        
+rdswmin = 0            rdwmin  = 0            rswmin  = 0            prwg    = 3.22e-008  
+prwb    = 6.8e-011     wr      = 1            alpha0  = 0.074        alpha1  = 0.005      
+beta0   = 30           agidl   = 0.0002       bgidl   = 2.1e+009     cgidl   = 0.0002     
+egidl   = 0.8          
+aigbacc = 0.012        bigbacc = 0.0028       cigbacc = 0.002
+nigbacc = 1            aigbinv = 0.014        bigbinv = 0.004        cigbinv = 0.004
+eigbinv = 1.1          nigbinv = 3            aigc    = 0.69         bigc    = 0.0012
+cigc    = 0.0008       aigsd   = 0.0087       bigsd   = 0.0012       cigsd   = 0.0008
+nigc    = 1            poxedge = 1            pigcd   = 1            ntox    = 1
+xrcrg1  = 12           xrcrg2  = 5          
+cgso    = 7.43e-010    cgdo    = 7.43e-010    cgbo    = 2.56e-011    cgdl    = 1e-014     
+cgsl    = 1e-014       ckappas = 0.5          ckappad = 0.5          acde    = 1          
+moin    = 15           noff    = 0.9          voffcv  = 0.02       
+kt1     = -0.19        kt1l    = 0            kt2     = -0.052        ute     = -1.5
+ua1     = -1e-009      ub1     = 2e-018       uc1     = 0             prt     = 0
+at      = 33000
+fnoimod = 1            tnoimod = 0          
+jss     = 0.0001       jsws    = 1e-011       jswgs   = 1e-010       njs     = 1          
+ijthsfwd= 0.01         ijthsrev= 0.001        bvs     = 10           xjbvs   = 1          
+jsd     = 0.0001       jswd    = 1e-011       jswgd   = 1e-010       njd     = 1          
+ijthdfwd= 0.01         ijthdrev= 0.001        bvd     = 10           xjbvd   = 1          
+pbs     = 1            cjs     = 0.0005       mjs     = 0.5          pbsws   = 1          
+cjsws   = 5e-010       mjsws   = 0.33         pbswgs  = 1            cjswgs  = 5e-010     
+mjswgs  = 0.33         pbd     = 1            cjd     = 0.0005       mjd     = 0.5        
+pbswd   = 1            cjswd   = 5e-010       mjswd   = 0.33         pbswgd  = 1          
+cjswgd  = 5e-010       mjswgd  = 0.33         tpb     = 0.005        tcj     = 0.001      
+tpbsw   = 0.005        tcjsw   = 0.001        tpbswg  = 0.005        tcjswg  = 0.001      
+xtis    = 3            xtid    = 3          
+dmcg    = 0e-006       dmci    = 0e-006       dmdg    = 0e-006       dmcgt   = 0e-007     
+dwj     = 0e-008       xgw     = 0e-007       xgl     = 0e-008     
+rshg    = 0.4          gbmin   = 1e-010       rbpb    = 5            rbpd    = 15         
+rbps    = 15           rbdb    = 15           rbsb    = 15           ngcon   = 1
```

The other thing is to provide the initial conditions to CADENCE. I've set the node called Osc to a volt, to start out.

LTspice is a little different in how it works, internally. So it could be something else.

Comment: Thanks for all the trouble you  have gone through. But I tried 2:1 PMOS:NMOS gate length ratio but didn't help. I later found out that it's a problem for initial condition set up. But my worry is about in practical case, I could not set initial values all the time. So enforcing initial condition will create trouble ?

Comment: @Anklon With .tran in Spice, it turns out the integration method itself can affect the Q of the system and when using normal time steps, the Gear method tends to overdamp the response whereas the trap method tends just the other way. A remarkable bit of LTspice is that uses a specially modified trapezoidal method of integration which is absolutely unique to my knowledge. It is completely neutral in this regard. No other SPICE does it this way and because of this I have a lot fewer problems with oscillator startup using LTSpice and its modified trap integration method.

Comment: @Anklon In the back of my mind there is something else about LTspice that helps... something to do with dealing with getting out of local minima/maxima areas. It wasn't simulated annealing. It was something else. But it also gave LTspice a unique advantage for oscillators. But I can't recall the reference anymore and can't really say if my memory is accurate on this point. But I do know that all Spice simulators have issues here and techniques that have to be applied to get out of local "pockets" and that LTspice is usually worth trying if you have trouble here. It's free, too.

Comment: @Anklon I don't think adding an initial condition will cause you any trouble and I think it will solve problems. So just use it when it works for you. LTspice starts up with and without it. The only difference being the phase relative to \$t=0\$.